# Singleton or Object Caching?

Tags: design-patterns, caching, singleton

Are there ever any performance (speed & memory) benefits to using a properly-implemented singleton object vs. caching a single object and fetching it out of cache as it is needed?

Comment: That really depends on the implementation of your cache. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Aren't you just describing one way to implement a singleton? The method described can well be "proper" (Depends on the implementation of said language and framework).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't any difference, not only performance, but also logical. A singleton "caches" its instance in its own static field, so it's logically a cache as well.

And your cache should have a singleton-preserving-logic, which most caches don't have.

Distributed scenarios are a different story, but in that case you should have the data cached, rather than an instance.